# Why is `CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation` calling the `userIdentityDiscovered` block for all input entries?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, nsoperation

My understanding is that when `CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation` is executed, the `userIdentityDiscovered` block is called only when a user identity is actually found. (I assume this to mean a phone number or email address linked to an iCloud account.)

Instead, when I execute this operation, it calls the `userIdentityDiscovered` block for every single entry in the list.

Also, when the account is truly invalid, the `user` parameter in the block comes back **uninitialized**.

What am I doing incorrectly?

#### Code

```
    var emailInfos: [CKUserIdentityLookupInfo] = []
    for email in contact.emailAddresses {
        emailInfos.append(CKUserIdentityLookupInfo(emailAddress: email.value as String))
    }
    var phoneInfos: [CKUserIdentityLookupInfo] = []
    for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
        let phoneNumber = phone.value.stringValue
        phoneInfos.append(CKUserIdentityLookupInfo(phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
    }
    let lookupInfos = emailInfos + phoneInfos
    let op = CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation(userIdentityLookupInfos: lookupInfos)
    op.discoverUserIdentitiesCompletionBlock = { error in
        print("*** Complete")
    }
    op.userIdentityDiscoveredBlock = { (user, userLookupInfo) in
        print("*** found user: \(userLookupInfo)")
    }
    CKContainer.default().add(op)
```

#### Sample Output

```
*** found user: <CKUserIdentityLookupInfo: 0x618000270b40; email=notarealemail@notarealdomain.sldfkjsdaflskfjsdlkjf.com>
*** found user: <CKUserIdentityLookupInfo: 0x608000274600; phone=(555) 555-5555>
*** Complete
```

#### User Param is `uninitialized`

```
*** found user: <CKUserIdentityLookupInfo: 0x600000266d40; email=notarealemail@notarealdomain.sldfkjsdaflskfjsdlkjf.com>
(lldb) po user
 <uninitialized>
(lldb)
```

#### References

- [CKDiscoverUserIdentitiesOperation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckdiscoveruseridentitiesoperation)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm seeing exactly the same issue.